# Gazebo and MoveIt

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the last MoveIt quick start tutorial: moveit.ros.org/wiki/PR2/Gazebo/Quick_Start

When I run:
roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch

It outputs:
[pr2_gazebo] is not a package or launch file name

I searched for it and I cannot find it.
I followed all the previous tutorials, and they all worked. It wasn't until this one that I had issues.

I noticed that Gazebo is now "a stand alone project" has anyone resolved issues that may have come from this?

Also when I follow the command:
roslaunch pr2_moveit_generated moveit_planning_execution.launch

The program launches, yet no model is shown.

It gives: Robot model not loaded, and: Planning scene not configured

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65404/gazebo-and-moveit/) by [knalj](https://answers.ros.org/users/5176/knalj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-06-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem, but using my custom robot. Found that 1.9/Using_roslaunch_Files_to_Spawn_Models helps to build and launch a model with last Gazebo version. So probably modifying the pr2 launch to match the tutorial guide will work.

It seems that I have not enought karma to post links. You will find all the info in Gazebos wiki, just look for this specific tutorial.

Any way, I was using grooby-destop-ull and I needed to uninstall ROS and install the grooby-desktop alone release. Add by hand some needed packages and install from source Gazebo and gazebo-ros-package. I followed Gazebo wiki instructions for that. If not, there was no way of get gazebo working from ros...

Now I get this error as you to: Robot model not loaded, and: Planning scene not configured

---

Originally posted by [E1000ii](https://answers.ros.org/users/4878/e1000ii/) with karma: 178 on 2013-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0